# How to allow same SKU for different products?

Tags: product, attributes, sku

I need add same SKU for different product.

Example:SKU *xyz-1* will be common for product_1, Product_2, and product_3

Comment: I think this is a good question and might be asked more times. We have answers, so let's reopen it. And yes, having a SKU for more than one product is wrong in itself. *SKU = Stock keeping unit*, this is the common name to count the same product in the shelf.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt : let us reopen it and hope for good answers

Answer (score 7):

From a practical perspective, you can't. A SKU is a unique field used to identify a product, the same way you can't duplicate an ID in a database.
Doing this will require a huge amount of work and it is highly not recommended.

Comment: You have provided the exact answer. +1 for that. For your answer, I added an additional point. Hope you will not mind. :-)

Answer (score 4):

As @mbalparda said, you cannot do this. Because, sku of a product should be `unique`. This is because Magento uses sku value in order to uniquely identify each product. So giving same sku id may produce unwanted behaviour.

From your question, it is not clear ***why do you need same sku for multiple products*** . So I recommend you to leave `sku` attribute as it is and then create a new attribute for what you need to achieve. Let it be `common_reference`. Now set same value for those three products `reference_1`. Then use this attribute to do whatever you like to do.

Hope that makes more sense